# RemoteServiceException occurred in production release

Tags: java, android, android-vitals

I have an app on Google's Play Store and recently I have updated the app.
When I tested it all was fine, but some devices API 28 and above are showing this crash in Android vitals.
I have searched Stack Overflow and didn't find one is related to my case.

I tried to check the entire code base and couldn't figure it out.

Google doesn't provide much info but Android Vital shows this.

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2141)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8019)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I configured the ProGuard rule to expose some model classes and it went well.
I'm not seeing any issues so far.

Comment: Not an answer to the question. What exactly did you configure? what caused a crash?

Comment: Exposed model classes that I used in the project.

Comment: Could you please share some code as well for better understanding ?